# Code inside a task expression is executed before the task is created

Tags: f#

Consider the following:

```ml
let makeTask n =
    task { return longRunningFunc n }
```

Under the assumption that everything inside the curly braces is part of the task, I would expect this to be equivalent to:

```ml
let makeTask n =
    Task.Run(fun () -> longRunningFunc n)
```

But it is apparently actually equivalent to:

```ml
let makeTask n =
    let value = longRunningFunc n
    Task.Run(fun () -> value)
```

Which is both unexpected and far less desirable, for example, when attempting to run many such tasks in parallel:

```ml
let myTask =
    Array.init 100 makeTask   // oops: calls to longRunningFunc occur sequentially
        |> Task.WhenAll
```

Note that the `async` builder behaves as expected. I understand that tasks are "hot", while F# asyncs are "cold", but I don't think that explains this discrepancy.

My questions:

1. Why does the `task` builder behave this way, and is it documented anywhere?
2. Is it possible to get the `task` builder to move the call to `longRunningFunc` into `Task.Run`, as expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The F# compiler team [says this is the correct behavior](https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/issues/15779). Executing a dummy task at the top of the task expression (e.g. `do! Task.Delay(1)`) would fix the problem, but isn't very elegant. Oh well.